# What is the practical use of the 10's complement

Tags: digital-logic

I apologize if the question from the title is too basic but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere. Everyone explains the 10's complement with examples of how to obtain it which I understood, but nobody gives a practical real world example where it can actually be useful to achieve something.

For example. The 2's complement is a technique used by digital machines that can only understand voltage levels of 1s and 0s at the very low level to represent negative numbers and do subtractions.

But the ten complement cannot be used in the digital world I assume at least not by the hardware itself. It could I guess be used by the software for example in a written program but I can't think why would someone want to do that and what benefit it would bring. I assume it won't improve the computation speed of a program in any way.

So then again. What is the practical use of the ten's complement? Does it have any practical application whatsoever? I assume it can make some operations faster if one masters it and can help you understand the other complements better but other than that it is used in any other way? Is it used in algorithms or something like that? Can it improve someone's code if used properly? Can you please give an example where it makes things easier or is it used at all?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you come across this? Might it have been \$10_2\$'s complement?

Answer (score 6):

There were many *decimal* computers and calculators before binary became ubiquitous. On these, 10s-complement was used for subtraction in the same way that 2s-complement is used on a binary machine.

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Comment: Well...what you are calling a **decimal computer** would actually have been a **binary computer** using a **binary-coded decimal** representation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson no. Sometimes, but not always. In any case it's immaterial. Just talking about machines where arithmetic is decimal.

Comment: Are you saying that there were computers where each individual wire had ten possible states? Perhaps you should clarify what exactly you mean by **decimal computer**.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ten wires, one-hot, e.g. Harvard Mark I or ENIAC.

Comment: (or, of course, mechanical calculators)

Comment: Perhaps I'm picking nits, but I would call that a binary computer with a one-hot encoding.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I wouldn't, because nowhere are the values that make up a given quantity *related by powers of two*. BCD has 1,2,4,8 and BCD arithmetic can be done as binary arithmetic with a fixup. But decimal machines are really decimal at heart, with designs inspired by the spinning wheels of mechanical calculators and Babbage's machines.

Comment: The possible confusion I see is that there were also **ternary** computers that conveyed three possible states **per wire**. So if you call something a **decimal computer** but it really has just two possible states **per wire** then the terminology might be confusing. I'm not saying you are wrong; just that the wording might be confusing to a newbie.

Answer (score 5):

10's complement (and 9's complement) is useful in BCD (binary-coded decimal) math, in particular BCD subtraction.

Take 456, 10's complement is 544. Add that to 888 in BCD and you get 432 with a carry, which is the answer for 888-456.

It's analogous to 2's complement and 1's complement in binary math.

BCD math is used where the overhead of converting to and from binary is excessive (eg. pocket calculator chips) and perhaps in cases when round-off errors are unacceptable.

Comment: thank you for the answer!